# Does attack power affect magic?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I've found some form of leg clothing for everyone, but I'm wondering if making my mage wear a loincloth would be a good idea. He's in the back so he can't get hit, but does the +1 attack power bonus affect his magical attacks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Attack Power represents the damage output of the character's physical
>   attack. Attack Power is based on Strength, skills and equipped weapon.

[Source](http://www.gamebanshee.com/legendofgrimrock/attributes.php)

Comment: So, I take it that's a "no" then...

Comment: It's definitely a no go, sorry :).